# Gmail API handle large amounts of requests

Tags: c#, optimization, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to take some benchmarks for how long it takes to some operations on Gmail messages with a mailbox containing a large amount of emails. I am using OAuth and a Gmail account with over 200GB of messages and the way I am currently going about it is fairly naive. I have a loop iterating infinitely until there is no longer a nextPageToken in the response to list messages. When the response comes in for the list of messages on the page, I iterate through the messages and use their message ID to get the information for the entire email (in RAW format). I have the Page Size set at 50.

The issue that I keep running into is an "Insufficient Memory" exception for my application. I am not entirely sure why this is as I completely process each page before moving onto the next request.

The process flow goes something like this:

request list of messages -> process page of 50 messages (each individual message must make a request to get full raw information) -> print message data on screen -> request new page with the previous responses' NextPageToken -> continue until no token is left.

```
// Here is the core logic in the main function that handles getting the list of messages and calling the helper function.

 using (StreamWriter oFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), backupFile)))
            {

                ListMessagesResponse response = null;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (response != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.NextPageToken))
                        break;

                    Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest req = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
                    req.IncludeSpamTrash = false;
                    req.MaxResults = 50;

                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        req.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        response = req.Execute();
                    }
                    catch (Exception except)
                    {
                        oFile.Write(except + "\n" + "\n");
                    }


                    foreach (Message message in response.Messages)
                    {
                        if (DisplayMessage(service, oFile, message) == false)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


// Here is the helper function to display the messages
public static bool DisplayMessage(GmailService _service, StreamWriter _fileWriter, Message _message)
        {
            var emailInfoRequest = _service.Users.Messages.Get("me", _message.Id);
            emailInfoRequest.Format = Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;

            Message emailInfoResponse = null;
            try
            {
                emailInfoResponse = emailInfoRequest.Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception except)
            {
                _fileWriter.Write(except + "\n" + "\n");
            }

            if (emailInfoResponse != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string email = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailInfoResponse, Formatting.None);
                    email += "\n";

                    Console.WriteLine(email);
                }
                catch (Exception except)
                {
                    _fileWriter.Write(except + "\n" + "\n");
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

What am I missing here when it comes to memory buildup? After processing 100+ pages of messages I start to see "Insufficient memory" and then a few requests later my application crashes. From what I understand, after the DisplayMessage operation is performed for a message shouldn't it go out of scope? Is garbage collection just having a hard time keeping up because of the rate of requests?

Also I would appreciate any help in how I can optimize processing this amount of requests. I understand that google recommends batching the requests and using gzip compression. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance . But from what I understand, these are primarily network speed improvements. At the moment, I am more focused on having my application complete without crashing locally. So these enhancements I can focus on afterwords.

Thanks!

Comment: Insufficient memory, is your heap space, consuming more memory then the heap thread can allocate instances of objects to, like your memory for heap, cannot contain 200gb of messages. 

You should make sure that each Message is clear from memory after processing it in "DisplayMessage". I am 99% sure this is your problem.

Try to monitor your memory usage in your IDE, and I believe you will confirm this yourself.
Or indeed the request itself, is garbage collected pr page.

Comment: I would suggest you use multiple threads to process "batches" of say 50 requests, meaning you create a separate thread for each batch you wish to process, and then upon completing a thread, you "kill" it, making sure the memory is garbage collected.

This will likely increase  your CPU usage, and enable you to complete the task faster, even if it is more CPU cycle expensive.

Comment: @MortenBork The multithreaded solution is a great idea and it is a great optimization technique. As for a quicker solution that does not require threading overhead, would implementing the IDisposable interface be a good idea? That way after I can immediately dispose of the message response after using it in "DisplayMessage".

Comment: I don't know precisely where you memory leak is located, so I can unfortuantely not answer that. 
When I look at your code, I wouldn't assume that this was your actual issue, because collections inside a while(true) look should be garbage collected. 

I am not sure if it is the collection itself, or perhaps the reference to the calling of

Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest req = service.Users.Messages.List("me");

I am not familiar with this listRequest endpoint, but it could this class that is the source of the leak.

Comment: It is why I suggest you open a memory monitoring plugin for your IDE, and try to run the code with it active, and check what objects are "clogging" up your memory, (IE. which object remain permanent) and then figure out which reference on said objects, is keeping them "alive" according to the gabarge collector, so you can avoid that reference keeping the memory alive. 

But that would "normally" require that a reference exists outside of the scope of the while(true) but used inside.

I don't see an example of that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022
Here is a guide as to how to check memory usage in visual studio? But I don't know your IDE, so this might not be relevant? :D